# python all returns false when comparing identical dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(df1.equals(df2))
print(df1==df2)
if all(df1==df2)==True:
    print("same")
else:
    print("diff")
```

and the output is:

```
True
      0     1
0  True  True
1  True  True
diff
```

My question is why all is returning false when comparing identical dataframes?

Comment: The issue is with `all`.  It is treating the `0` found in the columns and index as a falsy value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking *why*, this is actually showing a bit of unusual behavior of using the builtin `all` with pandas.  When `all` is looking at your DataFrame, even though all of the *values* of the frames are equal, producing a boolean mask of all True, you have a Falsy value in the DataFrame columns, which means that `all` will return `False`.

From the docs for [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

When this code is called on your DataFrame, it doesn't look at all at the values, but instead simply checks your column headers (since this is what is returned when running `for element in df1 == df2`), which in this case are `0` and `1`, and since `0` is Falsy, returns `False`

---

We can validate this by changing the columns to all Truthy values.

```
In [29]: df1 == df2
Out[29]:
      0     1
0  True  True
1  True  True

In [30]: all(df1 == df2)
Out[30]: False

In [31]: u = df1 == df2

In [32]: u.columns = [1, 2]          # all truthy

In [33]: u
Out[33]:
      1     2
0  True  True
1  True  True

In [35]: all(u)
Out[35]: True
```

---

The moral of the story is to not use builtin Python methods for this type of equality check when pandas provides the functionality for you with [`pd.DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html), which handles edge cases like index alignment which you don't want to have to manually account for.

Answer (score 2):

If need compare only values is possible use double `all`, first for compare per columns and then values in output `Series`:

```
if (df1==df2).all().all():
    print("same")
else:
    print("diff")
```

**Details**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a','b'])

print(df1==df2)
      a     b
0  True  True
1  True  True

print((df1==df2).all())
a    True
b    True
dtype: bool

print((df1==df2).all().all())
True
```

Or use [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
if np.all(df1==df2):
    print("same")
else:
    print("diff")
```

But [`DataFrame.equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) compare not only values, but also index and columns names between both `DataFrame`s.